# Primary key of temp table already exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query

```
declare @var1 int, @var2 int
set @var1 = 110
set @var2 = 300

IF object_id('tempdb..#tbl_Contract') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE #tbl_Contract drop constraint PK_#tbl_Contract
   DROP TABLE #tbl_Contract
END

CREATE TABLE #tbl_Contract
(  ContractID int NOT NULL
,  PersonID int NOT NULL
,  EndDate smalldatetime NULL
,  CONSTRAINT [PK_#tbl_Contract] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
     ContractID ASC
   )
)
...
```

But when I run this query the second time I'm getting an error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 There is already an object named
>   'PK_#tbl_Contract' in the database. Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0,
>   Line 1 Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

What I'm doing wrong? Why my primary key was not removed?

Should I use `GO` after `ALTER`? But I can't because there are some varibles

Comment: Why are you bothering to remove the primary key to a table right before you drop it? Just drop the table and forget about dropping the primary key. And yes you should put a GO before you create. Not really sure why you are bothering to name your constraint on a temp table. It is going to be dropped soon anyway.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks. I've just added `if object_id('tempdb..#tbl_Contract') is not null drop table #tbl_Contract` before creating and in the end of script. It seems works. Thanks. Please add your comment as an answer and I'll be able to accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to drop a constraint and then immediately drop the table. It is simpler to just drop the table. Also, there really is no need to name constraints in a temp table. You can greatly simplify your code like this.

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#tbl_Contract') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #tbl_Contract
END

GO

CREATE TABLE #tbl_Contract
(  ContractID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
,  PersonID int NOT NULL
,  EndDate smalldatetime NULL
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but  I can't use `GO` because I have variables that declared before

Comment: You could declare your variables after checking for your temp table.

Comment: I can't because I should use it before and after creating temp table

Comment: Is it possible to do this for a composite primary key? I'm getting OP's error when the temp table was created in a different connection, so there's nothing to drop!

Comment: @NReilingh: I had the same question. Figured out a solution though, posted as an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56798033/4228193

Answer (score 7):

For a composite primary key constraint on a temporary table it is much better not to name the primary key constraint, otherwise you will run into trouble with concurrent sessions. In the following way you can also add any number of indexes or check constraints without naming them:

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#tbl_Contract') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #tbl_Contract
END

GO

CREATE TABLE #tbl_Contract
(  ContractID int NOT NULL
,  PersonID int NOT NULL
,  EndDate smalldatetime NULL
,  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ContractID ASC, PersonID ASC)
,  CHECK (ContractID > 10 AND EndDate > N'2019-12-31') 
)
```

This allows you to avoid the pitfall of @mpag's solution in that you can further use the temp table in your stored procedure.  In @mpag's solution you cannot use #tbl_Contract outside the @Q statement.

You cannot create a primary key with the same name in different sessions, even on a temp table.  If you do not name the primary key and other constraints, they are automatically given a different unique name by the system for each session.

Otherwise you will have the following error when concurrently running the procedure from different sessions:

> Error number: 1750, error procedure:
>   dbo.ProcedureName, error line: XXX, error message:
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as @NReilingh raised in the comments (i.e. needing a composite primary key).  So, lets assume we want a primary key on the combination of `ContractID` and `PersonID`. The following works in that circumstance (assuming you have appropriate permissions for `EXEC`):

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#tbl_Contract') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #tbl_Contract
GO
DECLARE @Q as nvarchar(MAX) = N'
CREATE TABLE #tbl_Contract (
   ContractID int NOT NULL
 , PersonID int NOT NULL
 , EndDate smalldatetime NULL
 , CONSTRAINT
     [PK_#tbl_Contract' + CAST(@@SPID as nvarchar(6)) + N']
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( 
     ContractID ASC,
     PersonID ASC
   )
)'
EXEC (@Q)
```

This works because each connection at any one time on a given server should have a unique `SPID` value. `SPID` values are typically a double-digit number greater than 50; but are of type `smallint` so could be up to 5 digits long, potentially signed.

Remember to double up any single quotes in within your table's DDL (i.e. replace `'` with `''`)

Comment: I have the same requirement of creating a temp table with a composite primary key at the beginning of a stored procedure and using that temp table further in the stored procedure. The problem with the proposed solution is that the temp table does not persist, i.e. it is dropped when the EXEC is completed. After the EXEC (@Q) a simple SELECT * FROM #tbl_Contract will throw the error: Invalid object name '#tbl_Contract'.

Comment: good point. I had a similar problem with temp tables disappearing lately if not doing in SSMS (and leaving the window open). However, the OP seems to want to work in the tempdb, so I don't think I'll edit to use a different DB. The use of global temp tables (i.e. ##tbl_Contract) may give the object greater persistence, but I haven't tested. another solution would likely be to use a view in the non-temp db.